# Unit testing a functions whose purposes is side effects

Tags: c++, unit-testing

How would you unit test do_int_to_string_conversion?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void do_int_to_string_conversion(int i, std::string& s) {
    switch(i) {
    case 1:
        s="1";
        break;
    case 2:
        s="2";
        break;
    default:
        s ="Nix";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    std::string little_s;

    do_int_to_string_conversion(1, little_s);
    do_int_to_string_conversion(2, little_s);
    do_int_to_string_conversion(3, little_s);

}
```

Comment: You just ensure that the desired effect happened after the call?

Comment: I assume "side effect" in this example refers to the output to std::cout.

Comment: I do have to ask, though, why you don't just return a string instead of passing in a reference? You're completely replacing the one that you pass in, so you get no performance benefit out of avoiding the copy (since you don't avoid it), and if you returned the string, you could benefit from RVO (return value optimization).

Comment: The side effect is writing to the string in do_int_to_string_conversion.

Comment: You haven't given us a *specification* of what the function does. You cannot present us its code, and expect us to invent a specification. Because you imply the code is correct. What do you need a unit test for, then?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume this is just an example. Why can't you assert on the value of little_s after each call?

```
do_int_to_string_conversion(1, little_s);
assert_are_equal("1", little_s);
```

Answer (score 11):

Instead of worrying about how to test the function as it stands, I'd redesign the function to work a bit more sensibly, and test the re-designed version instead.

Right now, the function seems to have three separate (and only slightly related) responsibilities: do a conversion, modify an externally supplied string, and write some data to a stream. The stream to which it writes (`std::cout`) is also hard-coded -- a problem waiting to happen (e.g., conversion to a GUI environment is likely to be non-trivial).

I'd start by 1) splitting it up into logical functions, and 2) supplying the stream as a parameter.

```
std::string convert_int(int val) {
    switch (val) { 
       case 1: return "1";
       case 2: return "2";
       default: return "Nix";
   }
}

std::ostream &write_string(std::ostream &os, std::string const &s) { 
    return os << s;
}
```

I haven't included anything to (specifically) modify an externally supplied string -- obviously you can assign the return value from `convert_int` as you see fit, and the value of the string that was passed in wasn't being used anyway.

Truthfully, `write_string` is a good candidate to be eliminated entirely, but since you had that basic kind of capability, we'll retain it for the moment. Testing these is relatively simple -- for `convert_int`, we look at the string it returns, and compare to what we expect. For `write_string`, we can pass a `stringstream` instead of a normal `ostream` -- then we can use `.str()` to get that result as a string, and (again) compare to what we expect.

Comment: The string in this case is a proxy for something bigger, and external to the stuff that I am working on.  You asked in the comments of the last question that I asked that I include a small, compilable representative example of the problem.  This is what this code snippet is.

Comment: @David: okay, that's not really a major problem. For that matter, modifying the object (of whatever type) that was passed by reference isn't necessarily a problem. You still want to design the function to do *one* thing though. If it modifies an object, create a "clean" object, have it do its modification, then check the result -- though if its primary purpose is to modify an object, you might want to think about whether it should be a member of that object.

Comment: I asked this question to another friend of mine, and he had a similar response to you guys.  Including the write to std::cout was bad on my part because it confused things.  Still working on my question-asking-skills.  

The string in this case is a proxy for big-memory-mapped-data-structure that lives at the interface with what we are working on and pile of old fortran.  The int indexes the list of possible things to write to that location.

Comment: @David: okay, that makes the question considerably more understandable. If you don't already have a class to act as a front-end for the memory-mapped structure, I'd start by creating one. Then create a mock-object with the same interface, but easy access to results of operations, just for testing.

Comment: @Jerry: You said, "If you don't already have a class to act as a front-end for the memory-mapped structure, I'd start by creating one."  This is the subject of a bitter religious war at the moment.

Comment: A memory-mapped structure (MMS) is a naked object. It itself has no behavior. By creating a class that **has-a** relationship to MMS it will be easier to test. Instead of testing for specific types, you will be testing behavior. In your example you want to test that an integer is converted to its string/text representation. That is behavior.

Comment: @David: If it's a subject of heated debate, perhaps it would make sense to ask another question more specifically about its pros and cons (possibly with a more detailed description of that part of the situation). I think that format will work better than a long string of comments, and make an interesting discussion easier for others to find.

Answer (score 3):

If you *really* need to ensure that the output has been written, you need to break your dependency on `std::cout` and use another `std::ostream` during tests.

This might be as simple as a global variable:

```
#if PRODUCTION
std::ostream my_output = std::cout;
#else
std::ostream my_output = std::ostringstream;
#endif

void setup()
{
    my_output = std::ostringstream;
}

void print_hello()
{
    my_output << "hello";
}

void test_hello_was_printed()
{
    print_hello();
    ASSERT("hello" == my_output.str());
}
```

Or something similar to that effect.

Comment: This is also a good idea and one I didn't consider.  The right to std::cout is superfluous [my fault for including it].

Answer (score 3):

I'd change `do_int_to_string_conversion` so that it does just one thing (convert the in to a string).

```
void do_int_to_string_conversion(int i, std::string& s) {
    switch(i) { ... }
}
```

This has no side effects, so you can write a simple unit test that verifies the output (s).

If I needed a function that printed the result of the conversion, I'd put that in a separate function, and I'd parameterize the output stream.

```
void output_int(int i, ostream &stream) {
    std::string s;
    do_int_to_string_conversion(i, s);
    stream << s;
}
```

To unit test that, I'd pass in a std::stringstream object and check the result.

Comment: @Adrian: +1 -- you beat to it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like [Expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) to pass it some input and verify that its output is what it should be.